# creating a rechargeable battery pack

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, amperage

**My goal** is to have a rechargeable battery pack that outputs 5V 10amps.

**approach:** I think I could get a 2 cell 18650 battery management board,  (so that I may recharge the batteries and make them safer to use) passing the positive output from the bms of ~6.6V through a linear voltage regulator. The voltage regulator has an output voltage of 5V and up to 5 amps.

**would it be possible** to have 3 packs (the 2cell bms board) and take the output from the three linear voltage regulators, each 5V ~5amps, and wire them together to achieve 5V ~15 amps?

Comment: 2S max voltage = 8.4V. Max drop in linear regulator = 8.4-5 = 3.4V. Max dissipation in linear regulator = 3.4V * 10A = 34W. Hopefully you now realize that you should NOT use a linear regulator. Instead you should look at a DC-DC converter.

Comment: I guess I should ask you to clarify if the 18650 cells are lithium ion or LiFePO4?

Comment: the batteries are lithium ion

Comment: OK, well then the highest voltage is 8.4V, and for 5 or 10A, you will need to use a DC-DC converter unless you want to add a large heatsink and a fan.